# From code, how can you create a binding to a property on an object stored in an attached property?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, propertypath

We have an inheriting attached property which stores an object.  Further down the visual tree, we want to bind to a property on that object from code.

Normally we construct the Path portion of a binding like so...

```
var someBinding = new Binding()
{
    Path = new PropertyPath(AttachedPropertyOwner.SomeAttachedProperty),
    RelativeSource = new RelativeSource(RelativeSourceMode.Self)
};
```

That works, but we now want a property of the object stored in `SomeAttachedProperty`.  I take it we're supposed to use the string representation?

Also, while researching this, I found this on MSDN: [Property Path Syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645024(v=vs.95).aspx)

The concerning part is down under the heading 'PropertyPathInCode'

> If you construct a PropertyPath from a DependencyProperty, that PropertyPath is not usable as a Binding.Path, it is only usable for animation targeting. The Path value for the constructed PropertyPath from a DependencyProperty is the string value (0), which is a sentinel value used by the binding engine for an invalid path.

...which doesn't make sense to me since it appears to work fine. Am I missing something? Have we been doing all of our code bindings wrong?

### Update

Reading the MSDN documentation comment (which I missed was Silverlight, but I don't think matters in this case), it says you can't use a Dependency ***Property***.  However, it says you *can* use a DependencyProperty ***identifier***, the identifier being what's returned from the Register methods.

In other words, I think what they're saying is what we're doing is valid...

```
var someBinding = new Binding()
{
    Path = new PropertyPath(CarClass.WheelCountProperty)
};
```

...but this is not.

```
var someBinding = new Binding()
{
    Path = new PropertyPath(MyCarInstance.WheelCount)
};
```

Seemingly confirming this, under the hood, Reflector shows it's essentially just doing this...

```
public PropertyPath(object value)
: this("(0)", new [] { value })
{
    ....
}
```

...so I think that scare was a red herring.

I think that also means I can do what I'm after like this...

```
Path = new PropertyPath("(0).(1)",
    SomeClass.SomeAttachedProperty,
    SomeOtherClass.SomeOtherAttachedProperty)
```

...which gets the value of the second attached property from the object stored in the first attached property.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just confirmed my earlier suspicion was correct.  Here's all you have to do to bind to an attached property on the value stored in another attached property...

```
Path = new PropertyPath("(0).(1)",
    SomeClass.SomeAttachedProperty,
    SomeOtherClass.SomeOtherAttachedProperty)
```

As stated in the update, for simple properties, this is also valid.

```
Path = new PropertyPath(SomeClass.SomeAttachedProperty)
```

...which essentially is the equivalent of this...

```
Path = new PropertyPath("(0)",
    SomeClass.SomeAttachedProperty)
```