# How do you set up a binding to a static property from code-behind? (WPF 4.5+)

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, wpf-4.5

In XAML, setting up a binding to a static property is simple...

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=(foo:StaticClass.StaticProperty)}" />
```

How do you achieve the same thing in code?

I've tried the following:

```
var b = new Binding(){
    Path = new PropertyPath(StaticClass.StaticProperty)
};

var b = new Binding(){
    Path = new PropertyPath("StaticClass.StaticProperty")
};

var b = new Binding(){
    Source = StaticClass,
    Path   = new PropertyPath("StaticProperty")
};
```

...but none of the above work.

This works to set the initial value, but doesn't update...

```
var binding = new Binding(){
    Source = StaticClass.StaticProperty
};
```

The only way I've managed to get it to work so far is like this...

```
public static Binding CreateStaticBinding(Type classType, string propertyName){

    var xaml = $@"
        <Binding
            xmlns    = ""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation""
            xmlns:is = ""clr-namespace:{$"{classType.Namespace};assembly={classType.Assembly.GetName().Name}"}""
            Path=""(is:{classType.Name}.{propertyName})"" />";

    return (Binding)System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Parse(xaml);
}
```

...but MAN does that annoy me I have to resort to creating dynamic XAML, then parsing it! UGH!! But hey... it works.

I have to think there's an easier way! So what is it?

Comment: Why not stick with MVVM?

Comment: lol... not really relevant, but the short version is I'm just trying to learn things about the language to remove a lot of code that's no longer needed.

Comment: You'll probably just end up adding "a lot of code".  That sort of code is similar to old school WinForms.   I understand where you are coming from though

Comment: "You'll probably just end up adding "a lot of code"". Glad you think you know my capabilities!  You're wrong, but I admire your confidence!  ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `PropertyPath` by xaml paserer is different from constructor of `Binding`. So you should use code in below to get it work.

```
var binding = new Binding() {
    Path = new PropertyPath(typeof(StaticClass).GetProperty(nameof(StaticClass.StaticProperty))),
};
```

Comment: Good find. Any idea why there is no mention of PropertyInfo as constructor parameter of PropertyPath? To me, this seems to be an entirely undocumented feature.

Comment: @Clemens Yes, msdn dosn't mention what is a property parameter should be, and I don't know way.  I just get the information from  the source code of `PropertyPath`.

Comment: Well they do actually explain the usage of a property path string (or a DependencyProperty in "target mode", i.e. for animations), but nothing else.

Comment: Great find!!  I was digging all through the source code for `Binding` and `BindingBase` trying to find out how this worked. I should've checked `PropertyPath` (which seems stupidly obvious now! It was late!) Ironically, my original XAML-based solution was actually created so I could examine the resulting `PropertyPath` for clues, but it didn't get me anywhere. That's when I decided to just try if the binding I got back worked, and it did, so I just used that.  But your way is *exactly* what I was looking for. Same result and no XAML parsing!  Like I said, great find!! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I needed to go deeper with this problem and bind to nested property of a static property which has non-privitive type: `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NativeName` (`Thread.CurrentThread` is a static property of Thread class, `CurrentCulture` is an instance property of Thread class, `NativeName` is an instance property of CultureInfo class).

in XAML binding path is set as:

```
<Window xmlns:threading="clr-namespace:System.Threading;assembly=mscorlib">
...
<TextBlock 
     Name="txtCulture" 
     Text="{Binding Path=(threading:Thread.CurrentThread).CurrentCulture.NativeName}" />
```

so in code I had to use PropertyPath constructor with *path and parameters* and write it like this (using [the approach which also works with DependencyProperties](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32890863/1506454)):

```
System.Reflection.PropertyInfo staticProperty = 
    typeof(Thread).GetProperty(nameof(Thread.CurrentThread));

var cultureBinding = new Binding
{
    Path = new PropertyPath("(0).CurrentCulture.NativeName", staticProperty)
};

txtCulture.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, cultureBinding);
```

Comment: Good answer. Interesting to see how you can 'tack on' extra properties further down the chain by simply adding them to the format string.